# how to refresh full screen and reload all component in react-native

Tags: react-native

I am using react-native, react-navigation. I want to refresh whole screen of my app using scroll view and re-render all component, can anyone give suggestion on that?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using. a flatlist , and there you want to refresh all items in flatlist / scrollview  you can do :

```
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  View,
  Text,
  StatusBar,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Image,
  ActivityIndicator,
  Linking,
  FlatList,
  RefreshControl,
} from 'react-native';

    <FlatList
              data={tripDataDetails}
              renderItem={({item, index}) => {
                if (item.data_type == 'user_activities') {
                  return this.renderSightSeeingCard(item);
                }else if (item.data_type == 'meeting_point_details') {
                  return this.renderMeetingPointCard(item);
                }
              }}
              refreshControl={
                <RefreshControl
                  refreshing={this.props.itenaryReducer.pullToRefresh}
                  onRefresh={this.onPullToRefresh}
                />
              }
            />
```

anad there in onRefresh again call the api to update the data.

Hope its clear. feel free for doubts

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can use **NavigationEvents** 
first of all import **NavigationEvents** from  **react-navigation**.

Here is my code.

```
   import { NavigationEvents } from 'react-navigation';
    import * as React from 'react';
    import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
    import Constants from 'expo-constants';
    export default class App extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
  <NavigationEvents
            onDidFocus={() => alert('Welcome')}
          />
            <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
              Hello word
            </Text>
            <Card>
              <AssetExample />
            </Card>
          </View>
        );
      }
    }

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
        backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
        padding: 8,
      },
      paragraph: {
        margin: 24,
        fontSize: 18,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        textAlign: 'center',
      },
    });
```

i use `<NavigationEvents onDidFocus={() => alert('Welcome')}/>` and it is called wvwer time you open the page.

hope it helps , feel free for doubts.